# AngularJs: Error compiling a ng-switch

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Code

```
<input type="text" ng-model="person.name" />
<div ng-switch on="person.name"></div>
<p ng-switch-default>And the winner is</p>
<h1 ng-switch-when="Ari">{{ person.name }}</h1>
```

what's wrong? I got `Error: [$compile:ctreq]` , but removing these 4 lines all goes ok.

I got this example on 'ng-book' (a very BAD book)

Comment: Shouldn't the `ng-switch` div wrap the `p` and `h1`?

Comment: Yes, this is the problem. 
I copy/pasted the code, so, another -1 for this book...
Write the answer so I can choose as best answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-switch` element needs to wrap the `ng-switch-on` and `ng-switch-default` directives (the latter ones require the former).

```
<input type="text" ng-model="person.name" />
<div ng-switch on="person.name">
    <p ng-switch-default>And the winner is</p>
    <h1 ng-switch-when="Ari">{{ person.name }}</h1>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7DJSd/

Comment: This is a very weird example actually. There will never be a `And the winner is Ari` appear. A very BAD book ..

Comment: Yes, I told you.. 39.99 $ lost